# Spring Boot setup security for testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm unable to configure correctly the security in my tests.
My web security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("USER")
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
        ;
    }
}
```

And my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Application.class, AppConfig.class, WebMvcConfig.class, WebSecurityConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TestControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(wac).dispatchOptions(true).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getTest() throws Exception {
        mockMvc
                .perform(get("/api/test"))
                .andExpect(status().isForbidden())
        ;
    }
}
```

I get a 404 status code meaning the security layer is not executed, so it is not configured correctly in my test class.
I tried to switch the classes from `@ContextConfiguration` to `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` without success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make the following modifications to your code:

```
   @Autowired
   private FilterChainProxy filterChainProxy;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(wac).dispatchOptions(true).addFilters(filterChainProxy).build();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I spent a whole day figuring out what I'm doing wrong :)

Comment: @jeremija Happens to everyone! Glad to help!

Comment: In spring-security 4.x there's a new approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30536710/integration-tests-with-spring-security

Answer (score 7):

As said in [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#test-mockmvc-setup) for Spring Security 4.0.4:

> In order to use Spring Security with Spring MVC Test it is necessary to add the Spring Security `FilterChainProxy` as a `Filter`. It is also necessary to add Spring Security’s `TestSecurityContextHolderPostProcessor` to support Running as a User in Spring MVC Test with Annotations. This can be done using Spring Security’s `SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity()`.

Example:

```
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TestControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(wac)
                .apply(springSecurity()) //will perform all of the initial setup to integrate Spring Security with Spring MVC Test
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: Just a note: This is necessary to use e.g. @WickMovkUser.