# Inject @AuthenticationPrincipal when unit testing a Spring REST controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-test

I am having trouble trying to test a REST endpoint that receives an `UserDetails` as a parameter annotated with `@AuthenticationPrincipal.`

It seems like the user instance created in the test scenario is not being used, but an attempt to instantiate using the default constructor is made instead: `org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.andrucz.app.AppUserDetails]: No default constructor found;`

REST endpoint:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/items")
class ItemEndpoint {

    @Autowired
    private ItemService itemService;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/{id}",
                    method = RequestMethod.GET,
                    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public Callable<ItemDto> getItemById(@PathVariable("id") String id, @AuthenticationPrincipal AppUserDetails userDetails) {
        return () -> {
            Item item = itemService.getItemById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException(id));
            ...
        };
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
public class ItemEndpointTests {

    @InjectMocks
    private ItemEndpoint itemEndpoint;

    @Mock
    private ItemService itemService;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(itemEndpoint)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void findItem() throws Exception {
        when(itemService.getItemById("1")).thenReturn(Optional.of(new Item()));

        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/items/1").with(user(new AppUserDetails(new User()))))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

How can I solve that problem without having to switch to `webAppContextSetup`? I want to write tests having total control of service mocks, so I am using `standaloneSetup.`

Comment: You need to [follow these instructions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test-mockmvc).

Comment: So there is no way to use standaloneSetup combined with authentication?

Comment: Where does it say that?

Comment: I am not sure, but how could I get a FilterChainProxy, which is required?

Comment: You can also use webAppContextSetup, while still retaining complete control of the beans in that context with `@ContextConfiguration`.

Comment: You can get a `FilterChainProxy` [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23335298/476716).

Comment: Nice. Could you please show me an example of I could mock the service layer in controller test while using webAppContextSetup? Should I create a test config class that creates mock instances and declare it in @ContextConfiguration?

Comment: Yes, that is what you should do. I suggest using `FactoryBean`s to skip any unnecessary auto-wiring.

Answer (score 14):

This can be done by injection a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` into your Mock MVC context or standalone setup. Assuming your `@AuthenticationPrincipal` is of type `ParticipantDetails`:

```
private HandlerMethodArgumentResolver putAuthenticationPrincipal = new HandlerMethodArgumentResolver() {
    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterType().isAssignableFrom(ParticipantDetails.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
            NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        return new ParticipantDetails(…);
    }
};
```

This argument resolver can handle the type `ParticipantDetails` and just creates it out of thin air, but you see you get a lot of context. Later on, this argument resolver is attached to the mock MVC object:

```
@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(…)
            .setCustomArgumentResolvers(putAuthenticationPrincipal)
            .build();
}
```

This will result in your `@AuthenticationPrincipal` annotated method arguments to be populated with the details from your resolver.

Comment: This is nice approach just be careful!
There is ~ 20 argument resolvers registered by default which take care of interesting types. In my case an Authentication parameter was handled by ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver and my handler was ignored.

Answer (score 7):

For some reason Michael Piefel's solution didn't work for me so I came up with another one.

First of all, create abstract configuration class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestExecutionListeners({
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.class})
public abstract MockMvcTestPrototype {

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext context;

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    protected org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User loggedUser;

    @Before
    public voivd setUp() {
         mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();

        loggedUser =  (User)  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    } 
}
```

Then you can write tests like this:

```
public class SomeTestClass extends MockMvcTestPrototype {

    @Test
    @WithUserDetails("someUser@app.com")
    public void someTest() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.
                perform(get("/api/someService")
                    .withUser(user(loggedUser)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

    }
}
```

And @AuthenticationPrincipal should inject your own User class implementation into controller method

```
public class SomeController {
...
    @RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "/update")
    public String update(UdateDto dto, @AuthenticationPrincipal CurrentUser user) {
        ...
        user.getUser(); // works like a charm!
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I know the question is old but for folks still looking, what worked for me to write a Spring Boot test with `@AuthenticationPrincipal` (and this may not work with all instances), was annotating the test `@WithMockUser("testuser1")`

```
@Test
@WithMockUser("testuser1")
public void successfullyMockUser throws Exception {
    mvc.perform(...));
}
```

[Here is a link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-method.html#test-method-withuserdetails) to the Spring documentation on `@WithMockUser`

Comment: The new Spring link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/test/context/support/WithMockUser.html

Answer (score 4):

It's not well documented but there's a way to inject the `Authentication` object as parameter of your MVC method in a **standalone MockMvc**. If you set the `Authentication` in the `SecurityContextHolder`, the filter `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter` is usually instantiated by Spring Security and makes the injection of the auth for you.

You simply need to add that filter to your MockMvc setup, like this:

```
@Before
public void before() throws Exception {
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(myAuthentication);
    SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter authInjector = new SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter();
    authInjector.afterPropertiesSet();
    mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController).addFilters(authInjector).build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My @AuthenticationPrincipal is expecting a Jwt, so had to implement a custom argument resolver that implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.

```
public class JwtArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterType().isAssignableFrom(Jwt.class);
    }
    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                                  NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) {

        var jwtToken = Jwt.withTokenValue("token")
                .header("alg", "none")
                .claim("sub", "user")
                .claim("scope", "read").build();
        return jwtToken;
    }
}
```

In test:

```
@BeforeAll
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockMvc =  MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController).setCustomArgumentResolvers(new JwtArgumentResolver()).build();
}
```

And the mockMvc.perform can be used without passing a `RequestPostProcessor`.

Answer (score 0):

Simplification of [@pzeszko answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42486339/548473):

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    @WithUserDetails(value = "user@gmail.com")
    void get() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(URL))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(print());
    }
```

See:

- [Testing with a mock environment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-with-mock-environment)
- [Mock authentication in Spring](https://eliux.github.io/java/spring/testing/how-to-mock-authentication-in-spring)

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me and I found it really handy.

Create a `TestIUserDetails` service that implements UserDetailsServce in `test` package:

```
@Service
@Primary
@Profile("test")
public class TestIUserDetails implements UserDetailsService {
public static final String ADMIN_USERNAME = "admin@example.com";
    public static final String USERNAME = "user@example.com";

    private User getUser() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(USERNAME);
        user.setId(1L);
        return user;
    }
    ...
    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        if (Objects.equals(username, ADMIN_USERNAME))
            return getAdminUser();
        else if (Objects.equals(username, USERNAME))
            return getUser();
        return getPublicUser();
    }
}
```

Now, on your test:

```
@SpringMockWebEnvTestConfig
class AbcControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private User user;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        user = (User) userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(TestUserDetailsImpl.USERNAME);
    }

   @Test
   public void testAbc(){
     this.mvc.perform(post(endpoint).with(user(user))
     ...
     .andExpect(status().isCreated())...
   }
}
```