# Spring MvcTest controller @WithUserData gives null values at the controller with @AuthenticationProtocol

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am testing a Spring controller which accepts `@AuthenticationProtocol Customer cusomer` and `Customer` extends the `UserDetails` which is needed by the `@WithUserDetails` annotation for the test (Discussed Below).

The controller methods declaration is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deposit/address/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public CryptoAddressQrCodeResponse forTheTest(@AuthenticationPrincipal Customer customer)
```

After running the test, The customer values I get in the controller are all null. I tried the testing with `@WebMvcTest` and `@SpringBootTest` (Auto configured `MockMvc`) and I get the same results. For the `@SpringBootTest`, I made a custom class with a `UserDetailsService` `@Bean` which returns my custom customers.Is there a way to define the source of my custom `UserData` model ?

Comment: Please check solution given on this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/42486339/5725589

Comment: @LovaChittumuri any particular reason for that ?

Comment: Add your test class.